# iterating through an associative array in JSP

Tags: jsp, loops, foreach, associative-array

this is what i have
    myarray=[[value:32423412412, key:Home], [value:12312323123, key:Other],    [value:12312313232, key:Other], [value:23423523523, key:Work], [value:1312321, key:Work]]

how can i iterate and get both the value and the key for all?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
arraySize = myarray.size;
for(def i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
{
   def phone = myarray[i]["value"];
   def type = myarray[i]["key"];
}
%>
```